# Import Multiple Excel files to multiple tables using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have few excel files and each file has different column values and are not consistent.

I need to import the data from these files to its appropriate table in sql.

I thought of using For Each Loop container however i found that the column names must be the same in all excel files if we need to use the for each loop container.

Is there a way to iterate through all excel files one by one and import data from it?

I dont want to use multiple data flow tasks.

Comment: So you are asking how to loop over files with different column names and non consistent values as if they were consistent... Nice question!

Comment: Yes. each file will have its own column names. so i need a way to loop over each files in the folder and get the data of each file into its sql table. each file has a sql table associated.

Comment: the point is: if every file is different and should insert data in a different table, how do you think is possible to create a loop that save you time? The logical solution seems to create a single data flow for each one

Comment: the reason i use a loop is i want to iterate each file in that directory. every time my package is executed, it has to loop through each file and load the data

Comment: I think what @Naigel is trying to tell you is, "No, it is not possible".   You cannot use a loop to iterate through Excel files that have different column structures and import them to different tables.   You have to use a different dataflow for each possible column-structure.

Comment: That said, you could look into creating a BiML solution.

Comment: Thanks... I will check with BIML